# php symfony 1.1 detect android or iphone

Tags: android, iphone, symfony1, mobile-devices

i want to know whether it is a iphone or android phone, i used  below code for detection, 
But this displaying  as Mobile for both Android or iphone devices.....

But need like Android/iphone/ipad....

```
public function preExecute() {
...
    $context    = $this->getContext();
            $request    = $context->getRequest();
            $response   = $context->getResponse();

            print_r($request->getHttpHeader('User-Agent'));
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$ua = strtolower($request->getHttpHeader('User-Agent'));
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) {
    //android
}else if(stripos($ua,'iPhone') !== false) {
    //iphone
}else{
    //other browser
}
```

P.S. I would recommend that you upgrade to symfony 1.4 if possible! It provides a